# .htaccess rewrite url link

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my WordPress site, there were two URLs. 
europarket.info and europarket.ba

Now I do not use europarket.ba but the website still invites some pictures:

http://europarket.ba/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image.jpg

Is it possible over htaccess to change old link to new:

http://europarket.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/image.jpg

I tried to change link in MySql database but for some reason when I change site will not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^europarket\.ba$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://europarket.info%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```